# All colours are loaded in Tailwind (Laravel) but the only colour is not loaded

Tags: php, laravel

it doesn't load the one colour for me. `bg-gray-100` but `bg-gray-50` and others work. Why is that?

Comment: have you tried to actually compile any new changes? `npm run dev`

Comment: yes i have make this but dont work the colors are not back

Comment: Are you caching anything? Client side or server side? Try hard-reload in the browser.

Comment: You may use devtool to debug that

Comment: No it dont work idk its nothing caching

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` ?

If so then try to delete your browser cache.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).